# FS register is null

Tags: x86, seh

I have to implement a SEH based exception handler.
To start with, I have written the following sample code, where i am trying to register an exception handler using **fs** register.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION myHandler(
    _EXCEPTION_RECORD *ExcRecord,
    void * EstablisherFrame,
    _CONTEXT *ContextRecord,
    void * DispatcherContext)
{
    cout << "In the exception handler" << endl;
    cout << "Just a demo. exiting..." << endl;
    return ExceptionContinueExecution;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION myExceptReg;
    EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION *pReg = &myExceptReg;
    myExceptReg.handler = myHandler;
    DWORD prev;

    asm("movl %fs:0 , %eax");
    asm("movl %%eax , %0": "=r" (prev));

    myExceptReg.prev = (EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION*) prev;

    asm ("movl %0, %%eax" : "=m" (pReg));
    asm("movl %eax , %fs:0");

    //      int* ptr = 0;
    //      exception e;

    return 0;
}
```

When I debug the code, I see that the value of **fs** register is **zero**. and the program crashes after executing **asm("movl %fs:0 , %eax");**

Following is the sample of the assembly equivalent of this code.

```
000000000000401626:   mov     %rax,%rcx
000000000000401629:   callq   0x44d7a0 <std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))>
32                  EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION *pReg = &myExceptReg;
00000000000040162e:   lea     0x20(%rbp),%rax
000000000000401632:   mov     %rax,0x18(%rbp)
33                  myExceptReg.handler = myHandler;
000000000000401636:   lea     -0x13d(%rip),%rax        # 0x401500     <myHandler(_EXCEPTION_RECORD*, void*, _CONTEXT*, void*)>
00000000000040163d:   mov     %rax,0x28(%rbp)
36                  asm("movl %fs:0 , %eax");
000000000000401641:   mov     %fs:0x0,%eax
37                  asm("movl %%eax , %0": "=r" (prev));
000000000000401649:   mov     %eax,%ebx
00000000000040164b:   mov     %ebx,0x3c(%rbp)
39                  myExceptReg.prev = (EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION*) prev;
00000000000040164e:   mov     0x3c(%rbp),%eax
000000000000401651:   mov     %rax,0x20(%rbp)
41                  asm ("movl %0, %%eax" : "=m" (pReg));
000000000000401655:   mov     0x18(%rbp),%eax
42                  asm("movl %eax , %fs:0");
000000000000401658:   mov     %eax,%fs:0x0
50                  return 0;
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: This style of exception handling is only valid in 32-bit code.  64-bit code must follow the x64 ABI, exception handling is part of that.  It is table-based.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I am trying this for a 32-bit code, something is wrong here for a 32-bit code ?  What in this code makes it look like it is for 64-bit ?

Comment: If your registers are named rax, rbp, and rcx instead of eax, ebp and ecx, you are using 64bit.

Comment: I am compiling the code for 32 bit exe using mingw 4.6.2. The assembly code is what I found in the disassembly window during debug.

Comment: Are you explicitly passing -m32 when you build?  Or just assuming the compiler produces 32bit by default?  A 64bit executable would likely also explain why using fs doesn't work, since 64bit typically uses gs.

Comment: @David Wohlferd, you are correct. This is an issue with the 64 bit exe. Now I use the mingw32 instead of mingw64 and use -m32 option and i can see that fs has value 83 and the code works fine. Thank you!!... I thought it was 32 bit exe because i got 4 when i printed size of int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up:

The debug output shows that the code is being compiled for 64bit, and (as Hans pointed out) the style of exception handling being used is only valid for 32bit.  Ensuring that the code compiles for 32bit resolves the problem.

If this answers your question, please click the checkmark to the left so that karma gets awarded.

Comment: That comes nowhere near covering the massive problems with the OP's inline asm. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Besides the 64bit problem, you are gratuitously clobbering `%eax` (without telling the compiler).

I'm surprised it worked with your original source at all.  You got lucky that the compiler was overwriting `%eax` right away anyway, probably because you used `-O0` to make nasty code that never keeps anything in registers for long.  So your code would have broken as soon as you compiled with optimization on.

You also got lucky that the compiler didn't insert any instructions between the two asm statements which clobbered `%eax`.  Never count on registers or flags surviving between two asm blocks: use multiple instructions in a single block.

And besides that, `asm ("movl %0, %%eax" : "=m" (pReg));` tells the compiler that the asm statement overwrites `pReg` in memory, without reading the old value.  Again, only `-O0` saved you from this error, because it didn't optimize away the `pReg = &myExceptReg;` which doesn't need to be computed if `pReg` is going to be overwritten anyway.  With `-O1` or higher, **you should expect `pReg` to be uninitialized**.

---

#### Use something like

```
void* prev;
asm volatile("mov %%fs:0, %0": "=r" (prev));
...
asm volatile("movl %0, %%fs:0" : : "re" (pReg) : "memory");
// reg or immediate source, but not memory, are encodable with a memory destination
```

The compiler will take care of having variables live in a register when asked.  If it wants to store `prev` back to memory right afterwards, it will do so.  There's no need to force it to do so, and `"=r" (prev)` just generated a redundant reg-reg move from `%eax` to whatever other reg gcc decided to keep `prev` in.

Since (according to Hans), this code is only useful in 32bit, I left in the `movl` suffix for the store to memory, so the compiler can determine the operand-size when there's no register involved to determine it.  (i.e. when the value is a compile-time-constant address of a global or static symbol.)

Other than that, this source could compile to proper 64bit code, because it doesn't explicitly name any registers.

You could remove the `"e"` part of the constraint, and the `l` suffix, to get easy portability between 32 and 64bit for the 2nd asm statement, too, at the expense of forcing the compiler to waste an instruction putting the address into a register first, even when it didn't need to.  In 64bit mode, `mov r/m64, imm32` (Intel syntax) is what you need.  I used [an `"e"` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) instead of an `"i"` constraint, because arbitrary 64bit constants can't be encoded, only sign-extended 32bit.  Fortunately, symbol addresses can safely be assumed to be in the low 2GB, in the default code model.  The linker can fill in the addresses into 32bit relocations.

To make it work portably between 32 and 64bit with immediate operands, you'd need to get it to output "movq" for 64bit.  I think you'd have to use the preprocessor to test i386 vs. amd64.  `if(sizeof(void*) == 4) { asm("movl ..."); } else { asm("movq..."); }` might work, too.  That would make really ugly code with `-O0`, but the bogus side of the branch would still assemble (to `mov r/m32, imm32`) and never run.